# ndsolve with multiple initial conditions

Tags: differential-equations, equation-solving, finite-element-method

I am trying to solve a PDE using the `NDsolve` with initial and boundary conditions,

```
NDSolve[{D[u[t, x], t] - D[ D[u[t, x], x]] + D[u[t, x], x] == 10,
    u[0, x] == 2,
    u[t, 0] == 1,
    u[t, 2] == 1
    },
    u,
    {t, 0, 5}, {x, 0, 2}, MaxStepSize -> 0.01]
```

it worked. But when I trying to assign a initial condition: `u[0,x]=2` when `0.5<=x<=1`, `u[0,x]=1` elsewhere in [0,2] by means of `If`

```
NDSolve[{D[u[t, x], t] - D[ D[u[t, x], x]] + D[u[t, x], x] == 10,
    If[0.5 <= x <= 1, u[0, x] == 2, u[0, x] == 1],
    u[t, 0] == 1,
    u[t, 2] == 1
    },
    u,
    {t, 0, 5}, {x, 0, 2}, MaxStepSize -> 0.01]
```

the system returned me

```
NDSolve::deqn: Equation or list of equations expected instead of If[0.5<=x<=1,u[0,x]==2,u[0,x]==1] in the first argument {(u^(1,0))[t,x]==10,If[0.5<=x<=1,u[0,x]==2,u[0,x]==1],u[t,0]==1,u[t,2]==1}.
```

I know something is wrong with my initial conditions expression, But how I assign the initial conditions with an if condition. Or a better way to deal with it?

Thank you for your time!

UPDATE:

I followed the advice of @bbgodfrey by using DirichletCondition. it worked.

```
NDSolve[{D[u[t, x], t] - D[ D[u[t, x], x]] + D[u[t, x], x] == 0,
        DirichletCondition[u[t, x] == 2, 0.5 <= x <= 1],
        DirichletCondition[u[t, x] == 1, {2 >= x > 1, 0 <= x < 0.5}],
    u[t, 0] == 1,
    u[t, 2] == 1
    },
    u,
    {t, 0, 5}, {x, 0, 2}, MaxStepSize -> 0.01]
```

But comparing with the results of @kglr, the results are different. this is the results using  DirichletCondition, which also with an alert

> NDSolve::femcscd: The PDE is convection dominated and the result may not be stable. Adding artificial diffusion may help.

[image]

this is the result using Boole

[image]

Thank you!

Comment: Check the documentation for `DirichletCondition`.

Comment: Thank you @bbgodfrey, I have tried the DirichletCondition and it works!

Comment: Any `f[x]` that computes the correct values would be fine, if used with an IC in the form `u[0, x] == f[x]` (à la Bill Watt's, Alex Trounev's, or kglr's solutions), because `NDSolve` computes these values in the initial `ProcessEquations[]` phase to generate an IC vector (over the spatial grid) that starts the time-integration in the method of lines.

Answer (score 3):

I like `UnitStep`.

```
NDSolve[{D[u[t, x], t] - D[D[u[t, x], x]] + D[u[t, x], x] == 10, 
   u[0, x] == 1 + UnitStep[x - 0.5] - UnitStep[x - 1], u[t, 0] == 1, 
   u[t, 2] == 1}, u[t, x], {t, 0, 5}, {x, 0, 2}, 
  MaxStepSize -> 0.01] // Flatten

u[t_, x_] = u[t, x] /. %

Plot3D[u[t, x], {t, 0, 5}, {x, 0, 2}]
```

[image]

```
Plot[u[0, x], {x, 0, 2}, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

`Piecewise` probably works too.

Answer (score 3):

The third opinion, a simple modification of the author's code immediately leads to a solution. Note the solution near `t=0`

```
s = NDSolve[{D[u[t, x], t] - D[D[u[t, x], x]] + D[u[t, x], x] == 10, 
   u[0, x] == If[0.5 <= x <= 1, 2, 1], u[t, 0] == 1, u[t, 2] == 1}, 
  u, {t, 0, 5}, {x, 0, 2}]

{Plot3D[u[t, x] /. s, {t, 0, 5}, {x, 0, 2}, PlotRange -> All, 
  Mesh -> None, ColorFunction -> Hue, AxesLabel -> {"t", "x", ""}], 
 Plot3D[u[t, x] /. s, {t, 0, 1}, {x, 0, 2}, PlotRange -> All, 
  Mesh -> None, ColorFunction -> Hue, AxesLabel -> {"t", "x", ""}], 
 Plot3D[u[t, x] /. s, {t, 0, .05}, {x, 0, 2}, PlotRange -> All, 
  Mesh -> None, ColorFunction -> Hue, AxesLabel -> {"t", "x", ""}], 
 Plot[Evaluate[Table[u[t, x] /. s, {t, 0, .1, .01}]], {x, 0, 2}, 
  AxesLabel -> {"x", "u"}]}
```

[image: fig1]
We check the solution at `t->= 0`, and see that everything is not smooth there. We need a special numerical method to solve this problem. To eliminate the oscillations at `t-> 0`, add the option

```
s = NDSolve[{D[u[t, x], t] - D[D[u[t, x], x]] + D[u[t, x], x] == 10, 
   u[0, x] == If[0.5 <= x <= 1, 2, 1], u[t, 0] == 1, u[t, 2] == 1}, 
  u, {t, 0, 5}, {x, 0, 2}, MaxStepSize -> 0.01]
```

[image: fig2]

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: @Rick, you're welcome!

Answer (score 2):

```
sol = NDSolve[{D[u[t, x], t] - D[D[u[t, x], x]] + D[u[t, x], x] == 10,
      u[0, x] == 1 + Boole[0.5 <= x <= 1], u[t, 0] == 1, 
     u[t, 2] == 1}, u, {t, 0, 5}, {x, 0, 2}, MaxStepSize -> 0.01][[1]];

{u[0, .75], u[0, .1 .5]} /. sol
```

> {2., 1.}

```
Plot3D[Evaluate[u[t, x] /. sol], {t, 0, 5}, {x, 0, 2}]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: @Rick, my pleasure.